# iOS 11 push notification banner now shown while app in foreground

Tags: apple-push-notifications, ios11

In doing some testing on the iOS 11 preview, I've noticed that when I get push notifications while my app is foregrounded the OS displays the system notification that you normally only see when your app is not active.

I didn't see anything announced as having been changed, or any new APIs to change this behavior one way or another. Does anyone know or have links to documentation stating if this is intended, a bug, temporary, or what?

Answer (score 2):

There's an option for showing Push Notifications in the foreground in UserNotification framework.

```
 - (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center 
        willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification 
          withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler
```

Quoting the comment from the Framework:

> The method will be called on the delegate only if the application is in the foreground. If the method is not implemented or the handler is not called in a timely manner then the notification will not be presented. The application can choose to have the notification presented as a sound, badge, alert and/or in the notification list. This decision should be based on whether the information in the notification is otherwise visible to the user.

This could be the place to start looking for the answer.

Comment: @Mike. Yes, it came to replace Local and Remote Notification mess starting from iOS 10. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications

Comment: "If the method is not implemented or the handler is not called in a timely manner then the notification will not be presented. " This method is not implemented and the notification is still displayed.

Comment: notification is listed in notification center but banner not appeared anymore when app is foreground. ios 11.2 beta 2